# How to use regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-2.x

I must be missing something simple - whatever I do, I can't get my regex to match any strings:

```
[~] $ python2.7
Python 2.7.12 (default, Aug 13 2016, 19:37:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> s = "   405489796130    "
>>> regex = "\b[0-9]{15}|[0-9]{12}\b"
>>> for str in re.findall(regex, s):
...     print(str)
... 
>>> for str in re.finditer(regex, s):
...     print(str)
... 
>>> print("Hi")
Hi
>>>
```

The regex `"\b[0-9]{15}|[0-9]{12}\b"` should definitiely match the provided string (that string contains a substring of 12 digits...).

I even put this text and the regex into https://regexr.com/ and that website's regex found the substring - why can't Python?

Comment: I'm hardly a regex expert; I consult the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Comment: check out `print("\b")` ... note, backslash is an *escape sequence* in Python. use *raw strings* so Python doesn't interpret escape sequences: `print(r"\b")` or use double-escapes: `print("\\b")`

Comment: Please see my answer for a correct solution, mypetlion's one is not doing the right thing. I explained why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape your back-slashes.

```
regex = "\\b[0-9]{15}|[0-9]{12}\\b"
```

Comment: Use r-strings. This is why you'll see almost all regex examples in Python using them (except in cases where no back-slashes are used. `regex = r"\b[0-9]{15}|[0-9]{12}\b"`

Comment: I always use \\. I think that's just a preference thing where I'm in the minority.

Comment: Seconding the use of `r`. This is what it's made for, and it's specifically suggested as the solution to this problem in Python's documentation. Why in the world would you prefer double backslashes over a simple switch at the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

The regex patterns needs to be a raw string, in Python you declare a raw string with an `r` prefix like so:

```
import re
s = "   405489796130    "
regex = r"\b[0-9]{15}|[0-9]{12}\b"
for match in re.findall(regex, s):
    print(match)

>>> 405489796130
```

***EDIT***

[Deleted additional guidance]

Comment: It is not a good idea to copy others' solutions to your own answer. If you see other's answer is correct and yours not, you should remove it and upvote the correct answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried to comment that it works without the corrected syntax on your answer but SO requires 50+ reputation to comment. I did it correctly given the restraints

Comment: Correct way is to post your own good answers to gain 50 points (and more). Please remove my solution from your answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The corrected syntax doesn’t answer the question since it works without it. It is not a solution to the given question, it’s simply additional guidance.

Comment: [Here is your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tWBy0t/2), it matches really any strings containing 12 digits at the start or 15 digits at the end of the word

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Was that the given string in the question? I understand that it works better for use cases that he didn’t give but it wasn’t the question, it’s simply additional guidance. I’ll remove it from my answer to appease you